# Lucene.NET performance

Tags: search-engine, lucene.net

I have a website that runs of a third party search provider that is expensive. I am going to roll my own.

Is Lucene.NET capable of ~25,000 products (or documents), each with maybe ten attributes used for filtering? I am looking to do a "narrow/drill down" or "faceted search".

Does that sound like to much to ask from Lucene.NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used it with millions of entries and the performance was excellent. It was reliable and easy to get up and running. Highly recommended if you need full text search.